# Why am I seeing the page of a previous code on Taipy?

Tags: python, taipy

I've been making modifications to my code, but I still see the page's content of my previous code. Does anyone know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to hard refresh your page. If the changes are not updated, this might be due to your previous code still running in the background, which is why you are seeing your previous page. To avoid this, try killing your program after you have finished using it.